# Passing values from Flash to ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, flash

I implemented a kind of Bio metric login in Flash. Now, my flash is detecting person and authentication him. But all I need if after bio metric authentication some information to be passed from Flash to my ASP.NET as to initialize session.

Is it possible to pass authentication code from Flash file to ASP.NET page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something similar.

Keep in mind there's not much you can do to secure your application, as the .swf resides on the client and can be decrypted and decompiled. I'd recommend just storing an encrypted value in a cookie using a secret that keeps changing and read it from ASP.NET. It's no better than using an encrypted query string, though.

Comment: @Happy- Superb answer. Thanks!

Comment: Your knowledge is awesome. I have a doubt. While passing values from one page to another in ASP.NET using "SESSION" is that passing values can be found by hackers?

Comment: Session variables are stored on the server and are thus safe. A session is identified by a session ID, which is stored in a cookie. A session can be hijacked if a hacker can get a user's session ID through XSS, allowing them to access your page as the user, but they wouldn't know the value of the session variables, as that's on the server. You can learn more about ASP.NET session state here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the values with url parameters

Here is how you open web page from flash
http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?t=140468

Comment: Oops! this is not the answer I expected. I need secured transfer. URL transfer mode can be modified by users.